# StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml

Tags: jsp, html-escape-characters

I'm working in JSP, and I'm still fairly new at this. I need to change single aposthropy into `&#39;` or `&apos;`, and double aposthropy into `&#34;` or `&quot;` using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml. It compiled successfully. But it didn't work.

Here's my exact testing code.

`<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("cool 4' product") %>`

In view page source, the result is:

`cool 4' product`

not

`cool 4&#39; product.`

What's wrong? And how can I fixed it? Thanks.

Comment: Scriptlets are evil. Use the JSP EL and the [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info): `<c:out value="${toEscape}" />` or `${fn:escapeXml(toEscape)}`.

Comment: Oh okay, I never used that before, but let me try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to quote the StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml javadocs, as in 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29

> Supports all known HTML 4.0 entities, including funky accents. Note that the commonly used apostrophe escape character (') is not a legal entity and so is not supported).

So you have to do that manually.

Comment: Or use a HTML escape method that actually works, like [HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(String)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape-java.lang.String-) from the Spring framework (use a recent version! old versions like 3.x also miss the single quote)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

> `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("I'm coder")`

Escapes the characters in a String using HTML entities.

For example:

> `"bread" & "butter"`

Becomes:

> `&quot;bread&quot; &amp; &quot;butter&quot;.`